# List and add only new items to them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im adding a Item to a list with a forEach loop I only have one instance of that item so I only want to add it once.Then if there a new instance I want to add that to the list once

```
GameObject[] Rooms = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Rooms");

foreach (GameObject item in Rooms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Rooms.Length; i++)
    {
        if (item != rooms[i] || i == 0)
        {
            rooms.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is simply check if the list already contains the item and if not then add it:

```
foreach (var item in Rooms)
{
    if(!rooms.Contains(item)) rooms.Add(item);
}
```

Depending on the amount of objects I would recommend to use a [`HashSet<GameObject>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) instead since for a `List<T>` the `Contains` has to iterate the list everytime while for a `HashSet` it is a single hash access.

On the other hand the `Add` is more expensive on the `HashSet` but in your case this is the one that will be used less than the `Contains` ;)

---

Alternatively you could also use e.g. [Linq `Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union) (which basically uses the `HashSet` approach internally) like

```
rooms = rooms.Union(Rooms).ToList();
```

The result is a `List<GameObject>`

> that contains the elements from both input sequences, excluding duplicates.

This approach has another advantage: you can also filter out objects that do **not** exist anymore using an additional [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) like

```
rooms = rooms.Union(Rooms).Where(room => room).ToList();
```

using the [implicit `bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) as filter criteria

Comment: Thank you it's hard to find some of this info.